# DB sql Altibase 'as language java name' use

Tags: sql, database, oracle

my source code

```sql
REATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1 RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVE NAME 'test.quote() return
java.lang.String';
```

this code when I use on oracle `sql`
but I want to use `Alitibase` DBS for now
this `sql` print error

```
[ERR-31001 : SQL syntax error line 2: parse error AS LANGUAGE JAVE NAME'test.quote() return java.lang.String'
```

I need your help

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a function with PostgreSQL syntax.
The syntax `AS LANGUAGE JAVE NAME` does not exist in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Oracle can use Java for stored procedures and functions, see my answer for an example. Although the functionality might not work on your systems if the optional Java components are not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Altibase does not appear to support Java functions so you will have to rewrite the Java functionality as an Altibase stored procedure.

(I'm not 100% sure about this, but the "Stored Procedure Users’ Manual" document does not include the keyword "Java" anywhere near the relevant syntax diagrams. Since the Altibase documentation is very similar to the Oracle documentation, I would expect the Java syntax to be in the same place, if it existed.)

By the way, your Oracle example is not quite correct. Below is a fully working example of an Oracle stored procedure using Java.

```
SQL> create or replace and compile
  2  java source named "test"
  3  as
  4  public class test
  5  {
  6    public static String quote()
  7    {
  8    return "Hello World";
  9    }
 10  }
 11  /

Java created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1 RETURN VARCHAR2
  2  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'test.quote() return
  3  java.lang.String';
  4  /

Function created.

SQL> select func1 from dual;

FUNC1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello World
```